# MySql Database Design, in support of Android App

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I am working on an Android application that will allow users to gain access to certain sets of files and then sync them with their device for offline use.  Thus, when they first download my app, they will have no account or files, they will have to create an account, then enter an access code to gain access to certain file directories for download.

I have the majority of UI of the app completed, and it now needs to be 'plugged in' to a backend.  I am a little familiar with PHP as I have done a few dynamic websites, so I am familiar with working with phpmyadmin, but I really want to make this backend schema well made and able to handle business.

I don't know where to start to design the relational databases and all the other factors I may have not even thought about yet.  Does anyone have any good references, tutorials, anything that may help me take this next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to learn about data base modeling, these websites can give you a good start [example2](http://www.learndatamodeling.com/dm_overview.php#.UgtE_JIeCpc) [example3](http://creately.com/blog/diagrams/database-modeling-basics/)

or do you wish to learn about SQL coding?

Comment: i have a little experience with coding sql and for the most part the syntax and concepts seem pretty straightforward with a relatively small learning curve.  It's the scenario where I make something to get by now and make it work, but is doomed to fail big time on me if the if the app were to gain traction.  I'd like to build a reasonably solid back end foundation, conceptually and architecturally, from the get go if possible.

Comment: what type of database do you want to use? mysql, mssql, pgsql?

Comment: mysql because I have some familiarity with it

Comment: The way i've learnd SQL is by doing lots of projects over the past couple of years... but seems that you need to learn it pretty fast. It also seems like you need a pretty advansed database. But you need to start learning somehow.. I used thenewboston.org in the start, but when you start making database functions, inner- outer-joins, etc... you need to find an other place to learn. Maybe a book ;) But start with somthing simple, so you get the basic with SQL and Database